# How to know, which functions i can trigger by OLE Automation

Tags: php, automation, ole

i have an application, i registred it and i can start it like this and open a file:

$com = new Com('name.application');
$com->openfile('C:\test.txt');

Now my question, can i analyse the application which functions are triggerable (crazy word)?

in this example i can trigger: savefile(), too, but i had to ask the developer to get this information.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. [You can do it in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) but I can't find any way to do it with COM (or COM+) objects. I may be wrong about this as I am not a Windows developer by nature, and if there is a way to do it I would like to know as well...